# openresty with keycloak in docker, exposing host url as discovery

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, openresty

I have a compose-file containing two services:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    my_nginx:
        environment:
            OIDC_DISCOVERY: 'http://[my-test-server-url]:8081/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration'
        ...

    keycloak-container:
        ...
```

They are both running on a test server.
When I try to browse the app, `my_nginx` should redirect to `keycloak-container` for a OIDC token.
However, the NGINX reports the host url can not be resolved:

```
accessing discovery url (http://[my-test-server-url]:8081/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration) failed: [my-test-server-url] could not be resolved (3: Host not found)
```

If I bash to the nginx container, add the test-server under `/etc/hosts` (which again, nginx apparently doesnt use) pointing to the keycloak instance  and curl [my-test-server]:8081, I get the correct response:

```sh
[root@b68fd49a46fe /]# cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.21.0.8      b68fd49a46fe
#ip is that of the keycloak
172.21.0.19     my-test-server

[root@b68fd49a46fe /]# curl http://my-test-server:8081/auth/.../
{"issuer":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example","authorization_endpoint":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/auth","token_endpoint":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token","introspection_endpoint":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect","userinfo_endpoint":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/logout","jwks_uri":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/certs","check_session_iframe":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html","grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","implicit","refresh_token","password","client_credentials"],"response_types_supported":["code","none","id_token","token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"],"subject_types_supported":["public","pairwise"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA1_5"],"id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A256GCM","A192GCM","A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256","A192CBC-HS384","A256CBC-HS512"],"userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512","none"],"request_object_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512","none"],"response_modes_supported":["query","fragment","form_post"],"registration_endpoint":"http://my-test-server:8081/auth/realms/example/clients-registrations/openid-connect","token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["private_key_jwt","client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","tls_client_auth","client_secret_jwt"],"token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"claims_supported":["aud","sub","iss","auth_time","name","given_name","family_name","preferred_username","email","acr"],"claim_types_supported":["normal"],"claims_parameter_supported":false,"scopes_supported":["openid","address","email","microprofile-jwt","offline_access","phone","profile","roles","web-origins"],"request_parameter_supported":true,"request_uri_parameter_supported":true,"code_challenge_methods_supported":["plain","S256"],"tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens":true}
```

Now is there some way to make this work from within the nginx config? I'm using openresty with nginx (`FROM openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-6-centos`)
I spent most of the day trying to change things in the container hosts files, but they arent used within the scope of nginx apparently, as that reads from its own conf the resolver to use. I've made sure that it's set to `127.0.0.11` which should be correct.

Is there some way I can make a proxy_pass or similar to allow this to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server with systemd you can use the nameserver shipped with it, systemd-resolved, to resolve your hostnames from the /etc/hosts file.

You only need to add this to your nginx config http, server or location block:

resolver 127.0.0.53;

Use systemctl status systemd-resolved.service to see if it running on your server.